# Cant browse through Dictionary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax to send data and as a success, it sends some data back.

```
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'upload-prop-images' %}",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                data: fileData,
                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.newCard);
                    console.log(data.newCard.prop_name);

                    }
                }
            })
```

views.py :

```
def uploadPropImages(request):

    prop_obj = list(Property.objects.filter(user=request.user).values())
    new_card = {}
    for obj in prop_obj:
        if obj['prop_name'] == prop_name:
            new_card['prop_name'] = obj['prop_name']
            new_card['prop_address'] = obj['prop_address']
            new_card['prop_type'] = obj['prop_type']
            new_card['prop_images'] = '/media/' + obj['prop_images']

    return JsonResponse({'status': 'Done', 'newCard': new_card})
```

In the first code block where `success: function(data) {}`, `console.log(data)` prints the data I am sending, that is `{'status': 'Done', 'newCard': new_card}`, but when I print, `console.log(data.status)` or `console.log(data.newCard)`, I get `undefined` value. I cant understand why it prints `undefined` because I used AJAX may times earlier and It seem to work. It is how we can browser through the value of a dictionary in JAVASCRIPT, which in PYTHON is `print(data['status'])`. Is the error anything related to the keys defined inside the AJAX function: `processData`, `mimeType`, `contentType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call this

```
$.parseJSON();
```

Like this

```
               success: function (response) {
                var data= $.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.newCard);
                console.log(data.newCard.prop_name);

                }
```

Comment: It totally worked. But I dont understand. Previously I used it in the same way as show above, only one difference was that, that data being transferred to the server was text data rather than `formData()`. What is really happening?

Comment: success function get stringify response and you need to parse it to javascript object notation